# How to pick image from assets in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new in iOS development and currently dealing with a task where I have to show an `imagePicker` to pick image which are located in my project assets. I found that there is an ImagePickerController which helps to pick image from gallery or camera by the below code:

```
picker.allowsEditing = false
   picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
   picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
   present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but I want to show the picker only loaded with the images of assets of my projects instead of camera or gallery. How to achieve that?

Comment: Hint: sourceType

Comment: The word 'below' is not an adjective for your information.

Comment: Can I put an uiImageArray as srourceType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. The built in image picker is for accessing the user's photo library.

You are certainly free to present an interface offering the user a choice of images from your asset catalog or app bundle, but you will have to construct that interface yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I am new in iOS and Xcode, how can I achieve this, any source?

Comment: You would achieve it by programming. I've answered the question you asked. You assumed that UIImagePickerController might do this and I told you it wouldn't.

Comment: It would be great if I get some guideline!